# IO Costs of Redis Multi/Exec

Tags: redis

I would like to send Redis a multi/exec command like the following:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> MULTI
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> LPUSH "JIMMY" "ABC"
QUEUED
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> LRANGE "JIMMY" 0 -1
QUEUED
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> EXEC
```

However, I'd like to get an idea of the network I/O costs. It seems like there will be 4 trips and back and forwards, although I  think Redis will keep the connection open?

Would it not be faster to send all of those commands in one block? Is it even possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and this is called [pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining). You don't have to wait for the server to answer before sending the next command unless you need results of the previous command to do this (i.e. there is a data dependency). You will receive server replies in-order afterwards. Commands in your example could be sent in a single TCP packet with the minimal possible overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use EVAL with a LUA script, commands are executed on the server:

```
eval "redis.call('lpush',KEYS[1],'abc'); return redis.call('lrange',KEYS[1],'0','-1');" 1 JIMMY
```

Comment: what would the performance difference be of two equivalent commands - say updating a list, then getting all items in a list?

Comment: The performance factor for `LPUSH` is O(1); `LRANGE` is O(S+N), http://redis.io/commands#list, is that what you meant?

Comment: not really. I meant comparing the LUA script with the standard redis multi/exec containing the same commands

Comment: Oh, my bad. redis states that scripting, in general, is more efficient and offers lower latency than pipelining (scroll to bottom) http://redis.io/topics/pipelining, the big advantage with scripting is when you need results from a previous command as input into another one; with scripting, it's all server-side, whereas pipelining has to return results to the client. Scripting gives you more flexibility and costs less, I'd go with that.